# Flutter: Nested ListViews with different scrollDirections and non-fixed dimensions?

Tags: listview, dart, nested, flutter, shrinkwrap

The code below will cause an `exception` due to `unbounded vertical height` of the inner `ListView`. Now, I know that you can solve the problem by fixing the `height` of the inner `ListView`, but I don't want that. What I want would be `shrinkWrapping` for both `axes` or a work-around for this. Is it possible?

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: [
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        // some children with fixed dimensions
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```